# Adding success response after retrieval of member details

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way I could put this success message after the actual response? [This is what my response should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjYSh.png). This is currently what I have implemented [These are the member details, still without the success message I want to be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpKxX.png).

This is my code in API/Controller where I have successfully implemented error message (which will appear when requested member details are not found)

```
if((request.getGeneratedMemberNo() != null && this.clientRepository.getClientByMemberNo(String.valueOf(request.getGeneratedMemberNo())) == null) ||
                   (request.getFirstname() != null && this.clientRepository.getClientByFirstName(String.valueOf(request.getFirstname())) == null) ||
                   (request.getLastname() != null && this.clientRepository.getClientByLastName(String.valueOf(request.getLastname())) == null)){
                  result = new CommandProcessingResultBuilder()
                    .setStatus(ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED.getValue())
                    .setMessage(ResponseStatusEnum.MEMBER_NOT_FOUND.getValue())
                    .setPfsRefNo("<yyyyMMddhms-count>)
                    .setRefNo(refNo)
                    .build();
                  return this.toApiJsonSerializer.serialize(result);
                }
```

This is my MemberData.java where the requests are being called

```
@Data
public class MemberData {
    
    public String generatedMemberNo;
    public String idFeePaymentDate;
    public boolean membershipFeePaid;
    public String picPath;
    public String signPath;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public boolean capConBalance;
    public String lastPrintedDate;

    
    public MemberData (String generatedMemberNo, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.generatedMemberNo = generatedMemberNo;
        this.idFeePaymentDate = "THIS IS DATE";
        this.membershipFeePaid = false;
        this.picPath = "THIS IS PICTURE";
        this.signPath = "THIS IS SIGN";
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.capConBalance = false;
        this.lastPrintedDate = "THIS IS PRINTING DATE";
    }
    
    
    public static MemberData instance(final String generatedMemberNo, final String firstName, 
            final String lastName) {
        return new MemberData (generatedMemberNo,firstName, lastName);
        
    }
    

}
```

Where may I possibly put success message/this block of code?

```
                    .setStatus("Success")
                    .setMessage("Successful Retrieval of Member Info")
                    .setPfsRefNo("<yyyyMMddhms-count>")
                    .setRefNo(refNo)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a class `MemberResponse` with these properties:

```
public MemberData member;
public String status;
public String message;
public String pfsRefNo;
public String refNo;
```

When you return this object in the HTTP response, you will match the original requirements.

Comment: Where should I set the values for status, messages, pfsRefNo, refNo? Should I set it in MemberResponse class also?

Comment: You shouldn't set them in `MemberData`. From your post it looks like you are using some framework that allows responses to be built via `CommandProcessingResultBuilder`. Please check with whoever maintains this class or see other examples of this class that can show you how to build proper responses.